# PHP MySqlI meaningless error message. What ever could it be?

Tags: php, mysql

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in myFile.php on line 47

```
45 $statement = $con->prepare('call aProcedure(?,?,?)');
46 $statement->bind_param("sss", $str1, $str1, $str1);
47 $statement->execute();
```

Why?

PS: It works on my local system (F€#%"#€ i hate to say that)
The procedure executes successfully on both my local system and in production via. MySQL Workbench. Just refuses to run in production from PHP

Comment: Well, did you successfully create a `$statement`. Check with `var_dump()`, then `$con->error`.

Comment: is the connection to database correct? $statement is not successfully created

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a mysql but php error message, the `$statement` variable isn't an object. Is it `false` maybe? Try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

I had to renew the connection that i was reusing (works on my local system :// ).

```
$con = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$statement = $con->prepare('call aProcedure(?,?,?)');
```

I'm not accustomed to PHP enough to understand why there should be any difference.
I will accept the first sane answer to why this is so :)